# How to identify what coordinates that are within a specific distance of eachother

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, cluster-analysis, distance

I am trying to identify which coordinates fall within a specific distance of each other. Currently, my code is grouping all points together when it should be two separate groups.

```
from sklearn.neighbors import DistanceMetric
from math import radians
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter

data = {'Lat': [38.42447, 38.424474, 38.424493, 38.424394, 38.424457, 38.424434],
    'Long': [-77.402199, -77.402228, -77.402186, -77.398625, -77.398602, -77.398459],
    'Name': ['Truck', 'Truck1','Truck2','Truck3','Truck4','Truck5',]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['Lat'] = np.radians(df['Lat'])
df['Long'] = np.radians(df['Long'])

dist = DistanceMetric.get_metric('haversine')

df[['Lat','Long']].to_numpy()
dist.pairwise(df[['Lat','Long']].to_numpy())*6371000

final_df = pd.DataFrame(dist.pairwise(df[['Lat','Long']].to_numpy())*6371000,  columns=df.Name.unique(), index=df.Name.unique())

potential_grouping = []
for row, col in final_df.items():
for item in col:
    if int(item) < 15:
        potential_grouping.append(row)

outside_features = [k for k, v in Counter(potential_grouping).items() if v == 1]
acceptable_features = [k for k, v in Counter(potential_grouping).items() if v > 1]
print(acceptable_features)
current output: ['Truck', 'Truck1', 'Truck2', 'Truck3', 'Truck4', 'Truck5']
desired output: [['Truck', 'Truck1', 'Truck2'],['Truck3', 'Truck4', 'Truck5']]
```

Here is a crappy picture of what is happening...
The 6 small circles are currently being grouped (big red circle) but should be separate (2 green circles). This is happening because each coordinate (the small brown circles) are within 15 meters of one another. How can I insure that I get my desired output?

[image]

Comment: Do you need ANY two members of a green group be at most 15 (?) away?

OR, for each member of the green group, there need to be AT LEAST ONE member of the same group that's no further than 15 away?

Comment: @YuliaV Each coordinate needs to be within 15 meters of each other to be grouped. Each coordinate in both groups are within 15 meters of each other and that's why they are currently being grouped incorrectly. But the distance between 'Truck2' and 'Truck3' is 100+ meters away (those are in separate green circles )

Comment: Are you looking for a quick and inefficient solution or for a proper one? Clustering is known algorithmic problem, see e.g. https://towardsdatascience.com/clustering-101-how-to-choose-the-right-algorithm-for-your-application-fb1521ea13fc

Comment: It's not clear what your desired output is. "Distance smaller than d" is not transitive, so there is no equivalence relation, and no partition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way using [`DBSCAN`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html#sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN):

```
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN

# here Lat and Long are already in radians
X = df[['Lat', 'Long']].to_numpy()

# here 15 is your max distance in meters divided by earth radius in meters
clustering = DBSCAN(eps=15/6373000, min_samples=1, metric='haversine').fit(X)

# see groups
print(clustering.labels_)
# [0 0 0 1 1 1]

# get the result as you want
acceptable_features = df['Name'].groupby(clustering.labels_).agg(list).tolist()
print(acceptable_features)
# [['Truck', 'Truck1', 'Truck2'], ['Truck3', 'Truck4', 'Truck5']]
```